# Instance being mistaken for type

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a jest test where I have want to cast between types

```
// Instance Test
const a = Uint8.fromNumber(4)
const b = a.getCasted(Bytes)

test('instance', () => {
  expect(b).toBeInstanceOf(Bytes)
})
```

This test passes.

However, when I include a method from the `Bytes` type, typescript won't compile

```
// Method Test
test('method', () => {
  expect(b.getArray()).toStrictEqual([4])
})
```

Gives me the error:

```
ts/externals/uintXs.spec.ts:17:12 - error TS2339: Property 'getArray' does not exist on type 'typeof Bytes'.

17   expect(b.getArray()).toStrictEqual([4])
          ~~~~~~~~
```

I believe what the compiler is saying is that `b` is the type `Bytes` and not an instance of `Bytes`. However, that is not the case as proved in the `Instance Test`.

Here is the `getCasted` method:

```
getCasted<T extends External>(ExternalClass: T): T {
  return new ExternalClass(this.getUint8Array())
}
```

Here's the `External` interface

```
export interface External {
  new(uint8Array: Uint8Array);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
getCasted<T extends External>(ExternalClass: ({ new():T })): T {
  return new ExternalClass(this.getUint8Array())
}
```

Correct way would be,

```
export interface IClassOf<T> extends Function {
    // tslint:disable-next-line: callable-types
    new (... v: any[]): T;
}


getCasted<T extends External>(ExternalClass: IClassOf<T>): T {
  return new ExternalClass(this.getUint8Array())
}
```

TypeScript has no way to distinguish between Type or Instance as function itself is an object, `{ new():T }` tells TypeScript that what you are passing is a class and not the function itself.

Comment: thanks, but I believe I already did that. Added the `External` interface which includes the constructor signature

Comment: @AakilFernandes no it is not correct, the Argument and Return type has to be different, `IClassOf<T> is not same as T`. But in your method definition argument is `T` and return type is `T` which will never work. It is not External, it is type of the argument of method.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks!